# I couldn't find linux drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, acer-aspire

I have a Acer Aspire 5030 laptop and i'm noob for Linux systems.

i'm running this code `lspci -n` and pasting results to here : http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/
But i don't know what should i do know exactly.

I'm looking my hardwares manufacturer's website but there are Wİndows drivers, but there aren't any Linux driver.

Comment: See [Linux on Laptops](http://www.linux-on-laptops.com/acer.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page is just to conduct a preliminary check to verify if your device will work with Linux. You won't find drivers for Linux in most manufacturer's websites. Also unlike windows, in Linux you need not install drivers to get things working - sound, graphics, ethernet in most cases. The Linux installation takes care of everything. In some cases you might require proprietary drivers such as for NVIDIA graphics cards, but for that after you boot into installed Linux you will prompted to download and install.

For checking if your system works fine on Linux I would suggest you to get a [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) of Linux, like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) and boot from it. If everything works fine you need not worry. Just go ahead with installing Linux.

Comment: Thank you Chethan, i install Ubuntu but some graphical effect is slow. Because of this i'm worrying about graphic card's and CPU's driver.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is whether whatever flavour of Linux you are thinking of using will recognise all your hardware without needing additional drivers, and with most modern versions with recent hardware the chances are very good. As Chethan S mentioned, using a live CD is a good way of testing your laptop before you do a full install.

Doing a quick Google also often helps, and in the case of your 5030 there seem to be a few posts about getting wireless working so check these out.

In general, I have had good experiences with Linux 'out of the box' on Acer hardware - I run Fedora 14 on an Aspire One netbook (the original AA150) and on a 5735 laptop. I also have a 5040 that had Fedora installed for a while, but is now running Windows 7.